# Horror anthology with story about a woman who finds something in her bed

Tags: story-identification, horror, anthology-book

Looking for an elusive horror anthology published sometime before 1990. Included a story I believe to be titled “ Three in a Bed” about a woman who finds something other than her husband lying next to her. Cover has a purple border and I believe a creepy chair on the front.

Answer (score 5):

Just a guess, but there's a story "[Three in a Bed](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1746662)" in the anthology [Echoes of Terror](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?352727), which is at least kinda purplish.

[image]

It also appears in [The Ghost Book of Charles Lindley](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?293370) and [Lord Halifax's Complete Ghost Book](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?286432).